# Need help fixing a function for finding max_min_numbers in a text-file

Tags: c, file-io

I want to create a function with which I can find the lowest and highest number in a txt file. The problem is I don't know how to do it when there are letters and symbols involved. I also don't understand how to read a number, when it is glued to a letter or symbol.

I am basically stuck I created the function to read only from a text file full with numbers and now I want to make it to read the same numbers while ignoring letters.

```
int max_min_numbers(FILE *fp_in, int *min) 
{ 
 rewind(fp_in); // Because it is a part of a sub-menu
 char ch; 
 int  max = 0, N; 
 while ((ch = fgetc(fp_in)) != EOF) // reading until the file is over 
 { 
  if (isdigit(ch)) // if it is a number -->
  { 
   fscanf(fp_in, "%d", &N); //reads from stream
   min = max = N; 
   if (min > ch) min = ch; //checks values 
   if (max < ch) max = ch; 
  } 
 } 
 printf("Biggest number is: %d\n", max); 
 printf("Lowest number is: %d\n", min); //prints
}
```

Data read: a55 5 12 3 3a;

```
Expected output: 55, 3;  Actual output: 51,3;
```

Comment: Don't forget that after you've determined `ch` is a digit, you have already removed that character from the input stream.  And so the call to `fscanf` will only read from the character that follows it.  Use [ungetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc) to put the character back into the stream.  And before you update your min/max values, you should first test that the return value from `fscanf` is equal to 1, otherwise you cannot rely on the value in `N` being valid.  Finally, you must not set `min = max = N` inside the loop.  Your test is also wrong: compare with `N`, not `ch`.

Comment: `s/char ch;/int ch;/` [for a start]

Comment: Yet more errors: `min` is a pointer, so you must _not_ just set it to some integer value.  Instead, you probably want `if (*min > N) *min = N;`

Comment: Closing this question as "Too Broad" given the non-specific topic, and almost every line of code contains an error.  This is unlikely to provide any value to future visitors of the site searching for answers to a specific question.  The comments already provide valid feedback to help you, and you are welcome to post a new question if you are still having difficulty after implementing these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here, it prints maximum and minimum value and returns maximum value. It does not handle negative numbers. I would also suggest you to stay away from pointers if you are just starting to learn.

```
int max_min_numbers(FILE *fp_in, int *min) 
{ 
 rewind(fp_in); // Because it is a part of a sub-menu
 char ch; 
 int  max = 0, N = 0; 
 while ((ch = fgetc(fp_in)) != EOF) // reading until the file is over 
 { 
  if (isdigit(ch)) // if it is a number -->
  { 
   N = N*10 + ch;  //if previous digit is 2 and new digit is 3 N is set to 23
  }
  else
  {
    if (*min > N) *min = N; //checks values 
    if (max < N) max = N;
    N = 0; 
  } 
 } 
 printf("Biggest number is: %d\n", max); 
 printf("Lowest number is: %d\n", *min); //prints
 return max;
}
```